# Laravel redirect takes long time after request is finished

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I need to handle a csv file with more than 10K lines. It represents a list of product and the goal is to update the products table in the database.

My problem is that the global workflow takes about 15 minutes, but telescope display a duration time of only 15Kms (about 2,5 minute).

So my question is : why could a redirect takes 13 minutes after the end of the request ?

This problem is showing up on local development environment using `php artisan serve` but also on a dev-online environment (VPS). It does not seems to be due to serve command then.

I've dumped each steps of the controller method and I confirm what Telescope says : the controller ends at 2,5 minutes. So after that, it does nothing except waiting.

The redirect action is handled like so at the end of controller :

`return back()->withErrors($errorKey, $errorMessage);`

I'd like to wipe out this redirect time and I can't find why this is happening.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Do you have any DB query in your loop while reading through the file?

Comment: First, I parse the file to get all lines so that I build an array containing the lines informations. Then I read this table and perform update or insert if the Product is missing or not.
So there are two loops : one for file reading, and another one for querying database.

Answer (score -1):

I'd check the server load... You've just rammed 10K rows against a database in two and a half minutes. 13 minutes does seem a bit high but try again and then try and redirect away from that route... Does it do the same thing? If so, it's most likely the load on the server.

Comment: I thought about this too, but it's the same thing when redirecting on another page.  Moreover, I can check other pages during this long loading (on web preprod only because serve command seems to be mono-thread and can not perform two tasks at the same time). Plus, if I dupplicate the page (and so loading it earlier) I get the response while the original page is still loading. This seems to show that the script is completely ended, no ?